# Detecting space or text between node and its following-sibling using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an XML document which contains the following example extract:

```
<p>
    Some text <GlossaryTermRef href="123">term 1</GlossaryTermRef><GlossaryTermRef href="345">term 2</GlossaryTermRef>.
</p>
```

I am using XSLT to transform this to XHTML using the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="GlossaryTermRef">
    <a href="#{@href}" class="glossary">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|text()"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

This works quite well, however I need to insert a space between the two `GlossaryTermRef` elements if they appear next to each other?

Is there a way to detect whether there is either space or text between the current node and the following-sibling? I can't always insert a space `GlossaryTermRef` item, as it may be followed by a punctuation mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself my modifying the template as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="GlossaryTermRef">
    <a href="#{@href}" class="glossary">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|text()"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::GlossaryTermRef]">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone suggest a better way, or see any problems with this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, "node()|text()" is a longwinded equivalent of "node()". Perhaps you meant "*|node()" which would select the element and text children but not the comments or PIs.

Your solution is probably as good as any. Another would be to use grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::GlossaryTermRef)">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:if test="position() gt 1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Naah, that's not pretty at all.

My next attempt would be to use sibling recursion (where the parent does apply-templates on the first child, and each child does apply-templates on the immediately following sibling), but I don't think that's going to be an improvement either.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one? what do you feel?

```
<xsl:template match="GlossaryTermRef">
<a href="#{@href}" class="glossary">
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|text()"/>
</a>
</xsl:template>
```